# Remove DBUS support from an application

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, indicator-sound, smplayer

I'm trying to remove an application from the sound indicator menu (`smplayer`), and every time I remove it using `dconf-editor`, if I launch it again, it adds itself back. Is there an `.so` file or something somewhere I could remove so that smplayer no longer has DBUS compatibility and no longer adds itself to the sound indicator menu? I'm on Xubuntu 15.04.